# Globally Generated Vector Bundle on a Riemann surface

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

This is a very vague question, in fact not really a question at all more of a search.

I am studying some vector bundle theory on Riemann surfaces and would just like some non-trivial example of globally generated complex vector bundles of rank greater than one.

Does anybody have some examples which arise naturally in complex(& algebraic) geometry or topology?

Answer (score 2):

If $C \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a projective embedding of a Riemann surface, the normal bundle
$$
N_{C/\mathbb{P}^n}
$$
is globally generated of rank $n-1$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is the only interesting example I was aware of, I should have mentioned this in the post.